# Shouldn't $A \times B$ appear as a last step?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading **Goldblatt's:** *Topoi.* Here:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I am a little confused: He says that we're going to construct the product set without any reference to ordered pairs. [This is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFYsF.png) but he says that we are going to construct $A\times B$ and starts talking about it as if it were constructed, when he mentions $p_A: A\times B \to A$. I was expecting it to appear as some kind of last step, what am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goldblatt is *not* constructing $A\times B$; he is *describing* what $A\times B$ is from the perspective of category theory, that is, what makes the direct product the direct product. Goldblatt's point is that it doesn't matter how we code ordered pairs ([Kuratowski, Hausdorff, Wiener, or otherwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair)); all that matters is the "global structure," that is, that associated with $A\times B$ are "projection maps" $p_A$ and $p_B$ with the obvious properties. Indeed, he'll go on to show that if $C$ is some *other* set, with maps $q_A$ and $q_B$ which satisfy the same categorial properties, then $C$ is isomorphic-as-a-set to $A\times B$ - and in fact this isomorphism sends $q_A$ to $p_A$ and $q_B$ to $p_B$.

The point is that in category theory, constructions aren't defined by what they *are*, but by what they *do*. Exactly what set $A\times B$ is depends on how I code pairs as sets; that's weird, since the *idea* of $A\times B$ doesn't make reference to a specific ordered pair setup. The point Goldblatt's making is that underlying the idea of an ordered pair is this picture of a set with a couple arrows coming out of it, satisfying some properties. This is an example of a [universal construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+construction).

Replacing a specific set-theoretic construction with a category-theoretic one has some nice intuitive properties; but its real value comes from the impact it has in other categories. We can write down (as Goldblatt does) a categorial description of what the direct product is doing in **Sets**; but now that transfers to *any* category! We can speak of a direct product in **Groups**, or **Rings**, or (my personal favorite) [**BanAnaMan**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/22387/8133), and general arguments around direct products of *sets* tend to hold in arbitrary categories (note that there's nothing ensuring that direct products *exist* in arbitrary categories, but the *language* is always meaningful).

Comment: I guess that you accidentally answered another question I had in mind: What is the meaning of "without reference to ordered pairs"? I remember that when I read about the axiom of choice, several analysts from the first half of the $20^{th}$ century denied the axiom of choice but were actually using it without realizing.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle The point Goldblatt is making is that the role of $A\times B$ only relies on the pair of maps $p_A$ and $p_B$, with the properties he describes. We can prove all the basic facts about direct products (e.g. that there is a bijection between $A\times(B\times C)$ and $(A\times B)\times C$) just from the properties of the maps involved. Of course, asking what $A\times B$ *is* as a set requires us to talk about what an ordered pair is, but [that would be evil](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence).